# Do more joins equate to slower performance?

Tags: sql-server, performance, join

I'm working on a denormalized database dump, reconstructing the model so that we can access the data in our own system. Because the database is denormalized there is quite a bit of redundancy that I would like to 'ignore' in my reconstructed data model - only to make the model easier to read. I have a choice, and while I'm not looking for a strictly performant solution I would like to avoid excessive performance costs.

`table A` has a column `hTableE`, which is a denormalized reference to `Table E`. In my model I have `Table D` references `Table E` via FK. `Table D` also references `Table C` via FK, which references `Table B` via FK, which references `Table A` via FK. I think I have 3 choices:

1. Create an FK relationship from A to E. And then JOIN on that.
2. Join without an FK
3. follow the table FK relationships and use multiple joins to associate Table A with Table E.

My feeling is that No. 2 is the best option. But would not be obvious just from looking at the datamodel. No. 1 makes the datamodel harder to read (over 100 tables). No 3 is the most logically easy to 'rediscover', **but would probably come with a performance hit?**

Comment: Why would you think a foreign key make things worse? I mean, [smart people have written about this](http://www.scarydba.com/2015/09/09/yes-foreign-keys-help-performance/), why are you relying on assumptions?

Comment: I'm saying that looking a a visual diagram as in SQL Server, having this FK will make the diagram slightly more confusing to look at and may lead a new developer astray for a while. I want to avoid this. But thanks. I didn't know that a query optimizer could use an FK to ignore some joins on execution.

Comment: Another thing to consider is whether this `A.hTableE` column is actually redundant or not. It seems you have FKs: `D -> E` and `D -> C -> B -> A`. That doesn't imply a `A ->E` relationship. It might be that they meant to add a `A->E` relationship but they chose not to implement as an explicit FK (because that would create a "multiple paths" from D to E or because of some other undocumented reason).

Comment: And the (implicit) relationship that `A.hTableE` defines may actually be a different relationship than the one implied by the `D->E` and `D->C->B->A` paths (imagine a Employee (manages) Department and a  Employee (works in) Department). If that's the case then your option 3 is not correct.

Comment: Relationships between tables are important. If you avoid them simply to prevent confusing your developers temporarily, perhaps your solution is elsewhere...